What happens when an unidentified organism is discovered on Earth?
The scenario: An unidentified organism (Let's call it T) that originated from Earth is first discovered while some dudes were researching the geological formation of (insert location). It is approximately the size of a grown man and is currently unconscious so there is no way of knowing its behavior. There are no previous records of T ever existing. This scenario takes places in a time where the usage of AI is widespread and information is easily accessible via the Internet.

Who would the researchers have to contact in this situation?
How would T be contained in a controlled environment?
Would the existence of T be publicized? If so, how would the public react?

How would people tackle these problems in real life?

I would imagine that what happens would be entirely dependent on what story you want to tell. Is this a story of human hostility towards what we don't understand? Then they would probably kill it and summon all of its alien friends to come and destroy Earth. Is it a story about exploring the unknown? Then the researchers help it, much to the chagrin of their bosses and the public, and controversy ensues. This isn't a worldbuilding question as much as a story-writing question, the latter of which isn't on-topic for this site.

The answer depends entirely on what T is. Are you talking about some new species of leopard or monkey, or Bigfoot, or some weird tentacle monster covered in eyes?

VTC because (a) Posts are allowed to ask one and only one question, (b) questions about the decisions, choices, and actions of individuals and organizations are prohibited and (c) this is a classic off-topic high concept question (open-ended, hypothetical, opinion-based, all answers equal value, etc.). Please carefully read the [tour] and the following two help center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].

Note also that we periodically receive exactly this kind of question, "X happens, how does the world react?" There is literally no way to answer the question as both individuals and organizations will react based on opportunity, creed, conscience, education, and a thousand more variables - and the stimulus is (as usual) incredibly poorly defined.


Who would the researchers have to contact?
They would contact a zoologist specializing in that kind of organism (mammal, bird, fish, ...) and in that specific area.

How would T be contained in a controlled environment?
It would not. Why would it be contained? The normal course of action would be to let it be and continue to observe it.

Would the existence of T be publicized?
Of course it would be publicized. Discovering a new species is how a career in zoology is made. Publishing the discovery is sort of the entire point of making a discovery.

How would the public react?
The public will react with mild interest for about 5 seconds.
While discovering new large-ish species is not an everyday occurrence, it does happen from time to time. Articles and photographs are published in the newspapers, people look and them and think how cute, then people move on.

A new species of monkey, Cercopithecus lomamiensis or lesula, was discovered in the basin of the Congo River in 2012. It is quite cute, with "human looking eyes and a blue bottom". How did you react to the discovery?

The endearing lesula was discovered in 2012. Photograph from Hart JA, Detwiler KM, Gilbert CC, Burrell AS, Fuller JL, et al. (2012) "Lesula: A New Species of Cercopithecus Monkey Endemic to the Democratic Republic of Congo and Implications for Conservation of Congo’s Central Basin", in PLoS ONE 7(9): e44271, doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0044271, available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 Generic license.

Goodman's mouse lemur Microcebus lehilahytsara was discovered in Madagascar in 2005.

The supercute Goodman's mouse lemur Microcebus lehilahytsara was discovered in Madagascar in 2005. Photograph by user Z Thomas available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International license.

"The saola Pseudoryx nghetinhensis is one of the world's rarest large mammals, a forest-dwelling bovine native to the Annamite Range in Vietnam and Laos. It was described in 1993 following a discovery of remains in Vũ Quang National Park by a joint survey of the Vietnamese Ministry of Forestry and the World Wide Fund for Nature." (Word from Wikipedia.) A live animal was first observed in the wild in 2010.

While discovering new mammalian species is relatively rare, new bird species come to light all the time. Wikipedia has entire lists of new bird species discovered in the 2000s, the 2010s, and the 2020s. (Including a bird species, the Gunnison grouse Centrocercus minimus, discovered in 2000 in the completely unexplored and mysterious wildlands of Colorado, USA.)




